# UITextView text move up during typing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I create a `UITextView` and when I start typing, sometimes the text will go up a little pixels and keep typing it will go down to the original position, anyone know the reason for this? Thanks!

I upload a video to help you understand my quesiton. https://1drv.ms/v/s!AgJTGJ_qKByugwgor_onjRyJvw2t

Comment: Can you add a relevant gif and the code responsible for it?

Comment: Don't know how to add gif, I give a link to a video.

Comment: I think that's ok to have that much of flicker. After all text-views are not that good in type support.

Comment: Thank you, the flicker matters in my code, if I can find the reason it is better.

Comment: I don't find some good solution, my solution is set scrolled enabled at the time when I needed.